# Unable to delete the solr entry, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: php, solr

I am using http://code.google.com/p/solr-php-client/ to communicate with the solr from PHP. Every thing is working fine, but Delete.

I am using the `deleteById` function which in turn creates

```
<delete fromPending="true" fromCommitted="true"><id>13967</id></delete>
```

request, and it returns true.

But in actual entry is not being deleted. I don't understand what is wrong in it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you Commit?

Comment: What does fromCommitted mean then?

Comment: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages says its deprecated but no details given. I guess those two booleans are provided to prevent  deleting from committed/pending docs accidentally (if fromCommitted=false we cant delete a document thats committed)